# Peculiar behaviour with Mac OS X Application on El Capitan

Tags: macos

I have an installation made with Packages (v1.1.3), and my (codesigned) application installs fine.

And I can run it ONCE. Second time, the application won't open. It is as if OS X thinks the application still is running, because if I start the application from terminal `open -n /Applications/MyApplication.app` it DOES open. But not without the -n option. And there is no instance of it running, either shown in Activity Monitor, or with ps -A.

Doing `open /Applications/MyApplication.app` in Terminal, the open command will just "hang" indefinitely. No log entries in Console, nor any on stdout that could shed light on this.

Starting the executable directly in a terminal: `/Applications/MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication` works just fine though (!)

And one more thing: If I rename the app to say, "MyApplication2.app", it ALSO opens up correctly. But not if I change it back.

When in this condition (which is fully reproducable by uninstalling the package, then reinstall it), if I logout, then log back in, the application will open normally.

Furthermore: The application works fine on a freshly installed El Capitan (and on Yosemite), the problem has thus far arisen on machines that have upgraded from Yosemite to El Capitan.

I really have no idea where to look for the solution for this one...

Edit 1: Actually, this is reproduced each time I reboot the Mac. But if I then logout/login, it starts working. This is not acceptable!

Edit 2: Spindump from when **open** is in the "hung" condition:

```
Date/Time:       2015-12-14 10:46:25 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.11.1 (Build 15B42)
Architecture:    x86_64
Report Version:  22

Command:         open
Path:            /usr/bin/open
Version:         ??? (???)
Parent:          bash [421]
Responsible:     Terminal [253]
PID:             435

Duration:        10.00s
Steps:           1000 (10ms sampling interval)

Hardware model:  MacBookPro6,2
Active cpus:     4

Fan speed:       1996 rpm

------------------------------------------------------------
Heavy format: stacks are sorted by count
Use -i and -timeline to re-report with chronological sorting
------------------------------------------------------------



Process:         open [435]
Path:            /usr/bin/open
Architecture:    x86_64
Parent:          bash [421]
Responsible:     Terminal [253]
UID:             501
Task size:       2140 pages (-6)
Note:            2 idle work queue threads omitted

  Thread 0x1223           DispatchQueue 1         1000 samples (1-1000)   priority 31 (base 31)
  1000  start + 1 (libdyld.dylib + 13741) [0x7fff9ce485ad]
    1000  ??? (open + 13012) [0x1075572d4]
      1000  LSOpenURLsWithRole + 32 (LaunchServices + 191296) [0x7fff9c263b40]
        1000  _LSOpenURLsWithRole_Common(__CFArray const*, unsigned int, AEKeyDesc const*, LSApplicationParameters_V1 const*, ProcessSerialNumber*, long, __CFURL const**) + 387 (LaunchServices + 627634) [0x7fff9c2ce3b2]
          1000  _LSOpenStuff + 126 (LaunchServices + 156284) [0x7fff9c25b27c]
            1000  _LSOpenStuffCallLocal + 5692 (LaunchServices + 199633) [0x7fff9c265bd1]
              1000  CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 186 (CoreFoundation + 277482) [0x7fff984e6bea]
                1000  CFBasicHashApply + 128 (CoreFoundation + 277680) [0x7fff984e6cb0]
                  1000  __CFDictionaryApplyFunction_block_invoke + 22 (CoreFoundation + 277750) [0x7fff984e6cf6]
                    1000  _LSOpenItemsWithHandler_CFDictionaryApplier(void const*, void const*, void*) + 5103 (LaunchServices + 206768) [0x7fff9c2677b0]
                      1000  _LSOpenApp(LSOpenState*, unsigned int, FSNode*, unsigned int, unsigned char*, ProcessSerialNumber*) + 338 (LaunchServices + 208695) [0x7fff9c267f37]
                        1000  _LSLaunch(LSContext*, FSNode*, unsigned int, void*, __CFArray const*, AEDesc const*, __CFArray const*, __CFDictionary const*, unsigned int, audit_token_t const*, ProcessSerialNumber*, unsigned char*) + 8437 (LaunchServices + 218379) [0x7fff9c26a50b]
                          1000  _LSLaunchApplication + 5837 (LaunchServices + 228056) [0x7fff9c26cad8]
                            1000  LaunchApplicationViaLaunchDJobLabel(LSSessionID, CFMutableDictionary&, CFMutableDictionary&, __CFArray const*, char const* const*, __LSASN const**, __CFDictionary const**) + 1683 (LaunchServices + 235258) [0x7fff9c26e6fa]
                              1000  _spawn_via_launchd + 801 (libxpc.dylib + 80457) [0x7fff8e287a49]
                                1000  _xpc_interface_routine + 163 (libxpc.dylib + 24054) [0x7fff8e279df6]
                                  1000  xpc_pipe_routine + 249 (libxpc.dylib + 24411) [0x7fff8e279f5b]
                                    1000  mach_msg_trap + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 72854) [0x7fff95636c96]
                                     *1000  ipc_mqueue_receive_continue + 0 (kernel + 856352) [0xffffff80002d1120]

  Thread 0x1224           DispatchQueue 2         1000 samples (1-1000)   priority 31 (base 31)
  1000  _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52 (libdispatch.dylib + 32133) [0x7fff8d35bd85]
    1000  kevent_qos + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 98466) [0x7fff9563d0a2]
     *1000  ??? (kernel + 5844400) [0xffffff8000792db0]
```

Comment: Is the application built with Xcode and written in a language like Objective-C? What appears in the `/var/log/system.log` when launching and attempting to relaunch the application?

Comment: When the computer is hung, having just run `open /Applications/MyApplication.app`, does the application appear in the process list or is `open` still running?

Comment: Application is build with Xcode, and is C++. When relaunching the application, the actual executable never even gets executed, i.e. **open** stops and hangs before that.

Comment: In the "hung" condition, **open** is still running, and will be running indefinitely. I've updated the question with a spindump when this happens.

Comment: Oh, and there is no log entry in /var/log/systemlog at all when trying to relaunch.

Answer (score 1):

## Report the Bug

Given the behaviour is reproducible and your spindump output suggests the hang occurs within Apple's `LSOpenURLsWithRole`, [report a bug with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com).

Sadly, your bug is unlikely to attract any immediate attention from Apple.

## Demand Help from Apple's DTS

As this is likely a blocking bug, [open a Technical Support Incident (TSI)](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) with Apple's Developer Technical Support (DTS). Your Apple Developer membership includes two incidents and this situation is an ideal candidate for these incidents:

> ### Requesting Technical Support
>
> A Technical Support Incident (TSI) is a request for code-level support for Apple frameworks, APIs, and tools, and is available to members of the Apple Developer Program, Apple Developer Enterprise Program, and MFi Program. Submit a TSI if you cannot fix a bug, have trouble implementing a specific technology, or have other questions about your code. Your incident will be assigned to a Developer Technical Support engineer who can help troubleshoot your code or provide workarounds to fast-track your development. Responses are delivered via email in English, typically within three business days.
>
> #### Apple Developer Program and Apple Developer Enterprise Program
>
> Included with each enrollment are two Technical Support Incidents, which will expire at the end of your membership year. …

Comment: Thanks. A TSI has been filed and Apple 1st line support have been able to reproduce the problem but couldn't help, so it has been propagated to OSX engineering team...

Comment: Good to hear they could reproduce the bug. Be sure to push Apple for a solution or work around. Based on your questions, you seem to have discovered a few bugs in OS X recently!