# PackageMaker problem

Tags: macos, install

I'm trying to include a KEXT in an installer package (via PackageMaker 3.0.6(201) ) but I cannot get past following error:

> Could not rename "Payload"

There is pretty much NO INFO on this when Googling. Help ???

Answer (score 3):

PackageMaker is unsupported by Apple and would not of been updated to work on newer versions of OS X, most likely the cause of your problem.

The answer to [PackageMaker alternative?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167522/packagemaker-alternative) seems to provide an alternative [`pkgbuild`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html).

Comment: Thanks Stan. Sigh... :) Packages seems to break on El Capitan, as I get very strange behaviour of the [installation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218678/peculiar-behaviour-with-mac-os-x-application-on-el-capitan), so I guess I'm left with pkgbuild + productbuild. Ok. Some studying to do then.